# Maven automated deploy on google app engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I know that to deploy onto app-engine you can run the maven command:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

Which then prompts for the auth code and launches a browser to confirm you want to publish onto the app engine. I'm looking to automate this fully so it can just be run as a command from maven. I have the appengine-maven-plugin setup but there doesn't seem to be any functionality to skip the manual step.

Has anyone managed to solve this? I know you can deploy right from Jenkins but we're looking for a solution that could be automates if our Jenkins server was down

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The authentication flow which redirects you to the browser for login and consent is call three-legged Oauth because it involves three steps: 1) request for a token 2) login and consent 3) API call with token.

An authentication flow which does not involve user login and consent is called two-legged Oauth (server to server): 1) request for a token, signed with a private key 2) API call with token.  Server to server auth requires that you setup a service account with appropriate permissions (scopes).  You must also safely distribute the private key for that service account so that you can sign your requests.  See the [OAuth2ServiceAccount instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

The Bitnami Jenkins image actually does quite a bit for you out of the box.  When you setup [Push-to-Deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) you  launch an instance with gcloud.  That launch command specifies the scopes you want that images to have access too with the --scopes parameter, including `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin"`.  Permission to these scopes is given to the default project service account.  When Jenkins deploys your code, the service account credentials are made available through the Jenkins Google Oauth Plugin.

You can build another tool that will push code programatically.  You will need to create a service account which generates a JSON Web Token (JWT) Again see the Outh2ServiceAccount instructions.  The JWT is your private credential and you need to find a secure place to store it.  The App Engine SDK knows how to use JWTs to get auth tokens.

During runtime you can pass the path to the JWT file as the --service_account_json_key_file parameter to appcfg.py.  To plumb that parameter through the Maven plugin you'll have to use -DadditionalParams="--service_account_json_key_file " which is available on the tip of github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/master.  (Will be in App Engine release 1.9.27, but you can pull from Github until then.)

Comment: That is useful but I am asking if there is a way to initially automate the entire process?

Comment: Once you have acquired an OAuth token through the manual step, you can deploy with just `mvn appengine:update`.  But you can't automate away authorization.  You have to do some setup.